Error transcoding with FFmpeg: Error: Output format hls is not available
I am using FFmpeg library to transcode a video file into multiple resolutions and create an HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) master playlist.
It takes a video file as input but its does give me the output with HLS playlist.I got a error called "Output format hls is not available". Only the Output directory is creating
I am using FFMpeg 7.0 full build version and also tried older versions and ffmpeg essentials and also tried chocolatey.
if i remove the implementation of HLS from this code.it will create 4 different resolution videos in my output.
Note:I just tried this same code on my friend MAC Book by only changing the setffmpegPath: "ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath("C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe");" to his ffmpeg directory.
Its working perfectly in his mac book
import "dotenv/config";
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as path from "path";
import ffmpeg from "fluent-ffmpeg";
import crypto from "crypto";

ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe");

export const FFmpegTranscoder = async (file: any): Promise<any> => {
  try {
    console.log("Starting script");
    console.time("req_time");

    const randomName = (bytes = 32) =>
      crypto.randomBytes(bytes).toString("hex");
    const fileName = randomName();
    const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, "..", "..", "input");
    const filePath = path.join(directoryPath, `${fileName}.mp4`);

    if (!fs.existsSync(directoryPath)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(directoryPath, { recursive: true });
    }

    const paths = await new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.writeFile(filePath, file, async (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error("Error saving file:", err);
          throw err;
        }
        console.log("File saved successfully:", filePath);

        try {
          const outputDirectoryPath = await transcodeWithFFmpeg(
            fileName,
            filePath
          );
          resolve({ directoryPath, filePath, fileName, outputDirectoryPath });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error transcoding with FFmpeg:", error);
        }
      });
    });
    return paths;
  } catch (e: any) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

const transcodeWithFFmpeg = async (fileName: string, filePath: string) => {
  const directoryPath = path.join(
    __dirname,
    "..",
    "..",
    `output/hls/${fileName}`
  );

  if (!fs.existsSync(directoryPath)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(directoryPath, { recursive: true });
  }

  const resolutions = [
    {
      resolution: "256x144",
      videoBitrate: "200k",
      audioBitrate: "64k",
    },
    {
      resolution: "640x360",
      videoBitrate: "800k",
      audioBitrate: "128k",
    },
    {
      resolution: "1280x720",
      videoBitrate: "2500k",
      audioBitrate: "192k",
    },
    {
      resolution: "1920x1080",
      videoBitrate: "5000k",
      audioBitrate: "256k",
    },
  ];

  const variantPlaylists: { resolution: string; outputFileName: string }[] = [];

  for (const { resolution, videoBitrate, audioBitrate } of resolutions) {
    console.log(`HLS conversion starting for ${resolution}`);
    const outputFileName = `${fileName}_${resolution}.m3u8`;
    const segmentFileName = `${fileName}_${resolution}_%03d.ts`;

    await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      ffmpeg(filePath)
        .outputOptions([
          `-c:v h264`,
          `-b:v ${videoBitrate}`,
          `-c:a aac`,
          `-b:a ${audioBitrate}`,
          `-vf scale=${resolution}`,
          `-f hls`,
          `-hls_time 10`,
          `-hls_list_size 0`,
          `-hls_segment_filename ${directoryPath}/${segmentFileName}`,
        ])
        .output(`${directoryPath}/${outputFileName}`)
        .on("end", () => resolve())
        .on("error", (err) => reject(err))
        .run();
    });
    const variantPlaylist = {
      resolution,
      outputFileName,
    };
    variantPlaylists.push(variantPlaylist);
    console.log(`HLS conversion done for ${resolution}`);
  }
  console.log(`HLS master m3u8 playlist generating`);

  let masterPlaylist = variantPlaylists
    .map((variantPlaylist) => {
      const { resolution, outputFileName } = variantPlaylist;
      const bandwidth =
        resolution === "256x144"
          ? 264000
          : resolution === "640x360"
          ? 1024000
          : resolution === "1280x720"
          ? 3072000
          : 5500000;
      ``;
      return `#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=${bandwidth},RESOLUTION=${resolution}\n${outputFileName}`;
    })
    .join("\n");
  masterPlaylist = `#EXTM3U\n` + masterPlaylist;

  const masterPlaylistFileName = `${fileName}_master.m3u8`;

  const masterPlaylistPath = `${directoryPath}/${masterPlaylistFileName}`;
  fs.writeFileSync(masterPlaylistPath, masterPlaylist);
  console.log(`HLS master m3u8 playlist generated`);
  return directoryPath;
};

My console.log is:
    Starting script
    HLS conversion starting for 256x144
    Error transcoding with FFmpeg: Error: Output format hls is not available
        at C:\Users\asifa\Desktop\Genius Grid\Transcode-service\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\capabilities.js:589:21
        at nextTask (C:\Users\asifa\Desktop\Genius Grid\Transcode-service\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:5791:13)
        at next (C:\Users\asifa\Desktop\Genius Grid\Transcode-service\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:5799:13)
        at C:\Users\asifa\Desktop\Genius Grid\Transcode-service\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:329:20
        at C:\Users\asifa\Desktop\Genius Grid\Transcode-service\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\capabilities.js:549:7
        at handleExit (C:\Users\asifa\Desktop\Genius Grid\Transcode-service\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\processor.js:170:11)
        at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\asifa\Desktop\Genius Grid\Transcode-service\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\processor.js:184:11)
        at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
        at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:488:12)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12) 

I am using Windows 11 and FFMpeg version 7.0. I repeatedly checked, using CMD commands, that my FFMpeg was installed correctly and confirmed the environment variables path, experimented with various FFMpeg versions, and tried with FFMpeg full build Chocolatey package.
In Command Line its working perfectly:
PS C:\Users\asifa\Desktop\test fmmpeg> ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i .\SampleVideo_1280x720_30mb.mp4 -vf scale=w=640:h=360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -b:v 800k -c:v h264 -b:a 128k -f hls -hls_time 14 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_filename beach/480p_%03d.ts beach/480p.m3u8
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '.\SampleVideo_1280x720_30mb.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
    encoder         : Lavf53.24.2
  Duration: 00:02:50.86, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1474 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1086 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 383 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 000001ef1288ec00] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 000001ef1288ec00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 000001ef1288ec00] profile High, level 3.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000001ef1288ec00] 264 - core 164 r3190 7ed753b - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2024 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=11 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=800 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, hls, to 'beach/480p.m3u8':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf61.1.100
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264, yuv420p(progressive), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 800 kb/s, 25 fps, 90k tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
        encoder         : Lavc61.3.100 libx264
      Side data:
        cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/800000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
        encoder         : Lavc61.3.100 aac
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p_000.ts' for writing speed=15.5x
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p_001.ts' for writing speed=17.9x
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p_002.ts' for writing speed=17.3x
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p_003.ts' for writing speed=19.4x
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p_004.ts' for writing speed=19.3x
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p_005.ts' for writing speed=19.2x
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p_006.ts' for writing
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p_007.ts' for writing speed=19.4x
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p_008.ts' for writing speed=19.5x
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p_009.ts' for writing speed=19.5x
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p_010.ts' for writing speed=19.4x
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p_011.ts' for writing/A    =19.4x
[hls @ 000001ef12482040] Opening 'beach/480p.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[out#0/hls @ 000001ef11d4e880] video:17094KiB audio:2680KiB subtitle:0KiB other streams:0KiB global headers:0KiB muxing overhead: unknown
frame= 4271 fps=485 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:02:50.76 bitrate=N/A speed=19.4x
[libx264 @ 000001ef1288ec00] frame I:45    Avg QP:10.29  size: 60418
[libx264 @ 000001ef1288ec00] frame P:1914  Avg QP:14.53  size:  5582
[libx264 @ 000001ef1288ec00] frame B:2312  Avg QP:20.63  size:  1774
[libx264 @ 000001ef1288ec00] consecutive B-frames: 22.9% 11.9%  8.6% 56.6%
[libx264 @ 000001ef1288ec00] mb I  I16..4: 15.6% 32.1% 52.2%
[libx264 @ 000001ef1288ec00] mb P  I16..4:  0.3%  3.4%  1.2%  P16..4: 20.3% 10.0% 13.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:51.8%
[libx264 @ 000001ef1288ec00] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.9%  0.4%  B16..8: 17.2%  5.6%  2.8%  direct: 2.0%  skip:71.0%  L0:41.5% L1:44.1% BI:14.4%
[libx264 @ 000001ef1288ec00] final ratefactor: 16.13
[libx264 @ 000001ef1288ec00] 8x8 transform intra:58.4% inter:51.7%
[libx264 @ 000001ef1288ec00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 86.7% 94.3% 78.8% inter: 12.6% 15.0% 4.5%
[libx264 @ 000001ef1288ec00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 17% 42% 14% 28%
[libx264 @ 000001ef1288ec00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 19% 11%  6%  7%  8%  8%  9%  9%
[libx264 @ 000001ef1288ec00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 18% 12%  6%  9%  9%  8%  8%  7%
[libx264 @ 000001ef1288ec00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 44% 24% 20% 12%
[libx264 @ 000001ef1288ec00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 000001ef1288ec00] ref P L0: 78.3%  9.7%  8.8%  3.2%
[libx264 @ 000001ef1288ec00] ref B L0: 92.5%  6.0%  1.5%
[libx264 @ 000001ef1288ec00] ref B L1: 97.1%  2.9%
[libx264 @ 000001ef1288ec00] kb/s:819.63
[aac @ 000001ef128f7c80] Qavg: 452.137

When I use the .on('start', (cmdline) => console.log(cmdline))} code with the -f hls command, the error "Output format hls is not available" appears, as previously mentioned. But my Console.log looks like this if I run my code without using -f hls command:
Without -f hls command
await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
  ffmpeg(filePath)
    .outputOptions([
      `-c:v h264`,
      `-b:v ${videoBitrate}`,
      `-c:a aac`,
      `-b:a ${audioBitrate}`,
      `-vf scale=${resolution}`,
 
      `-hls_time 10`,
      `-hls_list_size 0`,
      `-hls_segment_filename ${directoryPath}/${segmentFileName}`,
    ])
    .output(`${directoryPath}/${outputFileName}`)
    .on('start', (cmdline) => console.log(cmdline)) 
    .on("end", () => resolve())
    .on("error", (err) => reject(err))
    .run();
});

Console.log is:
`Starting script
File saved successfully: C:\Users\asifa\Desktop\Genius Grid\Transcode-service\input\c9fcf43726e617a295b203d5acb7b81658b5f05f80eafc74cee21b053422fef1.mp4
HLS conversion starting for 256x144
ffmpeg -i C:\Users\asifa\Desktop\Genius Grid\Transcode-service\input\c9fcf43726e617a295b203d5acb7b81658b5f05f80eafc74cee21b053422fef1.mp4 -y -c:v h264 -b:v 200k -c:a aac -b:a 64k -vf scale=256x144 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_filename C:\Users\asifa\Desktop\Genius Grid\Transcode-service\output\hls\c9fcf43726e617a295b203d5acb7b81658b5f05f80eafc74cee21b053422fef1/c9fcf43726e617a295b203d5acb7b81658b5f05f80eafc74cee21b053422fef1_256x144_%03d.ts C:\Users\asifa\Desktop\Genius Grid\Transcode-service\output\hls\c9fcf43726e617a295b203d5acb7b81658b5f05f80eafc74cee21b053422fef1/c9fcf43726e617a295b203d5acb7b81658b5f05f80eafc74cee21b053422fef1_256x144.m3u8
Error transcoding with FFmpeg: Error: ffmpeg exited with code 2880417800: Unrecognized option 'hls_segment_filename C:\Users\asifa\Desktop\Genius Grid\Transcode-service\output\hls\c9fcf43726e617a295b203d5acb7b81658b5f05f80eafc74cee21b053422fef1/c9fcf43726e617a295b203d5acb7b81658b5f05f80eafc74cee21b053422fef1_256x144_%03d.ts'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found`


What does it say when you run it on the command line?

I updated the code once more.
I need to  transcode a video file into multiple resolutions and create an HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) master playlist.

Thanks, this is a better question. You can remove package.json, it's not useful information. The console.log is good - it says the error is coming from FFMpeg. This means the problem isn't your code. You say it works on a MacBook, but your code appears to be for a Windows machine. Again, what does it say when you run the command from the commandline? All indications are that this is an FFMpeg installation problem, not a coding error.

I repeatedly double checked, using CMD commands, that my FFMpeg was installed correctly, confirmed the environment variables path, experimented with various FFMpeg versions, and tried with FFMpeg full build Chocolatey package.

Can you answer the question?

I apologize for not understanding your question earlier. I just tested my Commands once more using the Command Line. It working well in CMD . I updated my code once  more

Thanks. It probably shouldn't matter but the command arguments I see are in a different order in the JS code than what you put on the command line. It would be good if these were the same just to be sure. For testing, can you change the FFMpeg command in your code to ffmpeg -demuxers and verify that hls is listed? You will need to change to .on('end',(stdout,stderr)=>{console.log(stdout); resolve()}) to get the demuxer output from stdout. You may also need to set stdoutLines to something like 1000 in the ffmpeg(file,{options}) block.

I followed your advice and made all the necessary adjustments, but the error persists. Also, I used ffmpeg -demuxers to double check and confirm that the HLS is Listed on my machine.

Okay. I looked a little closer and am I correct that you're passing a random name as the input file? If you add this: .on('start', (cmdline) => console.log(cmdline)) you should be able to see the command fluent is generating for FFMpeg. What does that say?

I updated my question once more with .on('start', (cmdline) => console.log(cmdline)).

Thanks again. Just to be clear: in your commandline version you're reading .\SampleVideo_1280x720_30mb.mp4 as input and in the other one you want to read C:\Users\asifa\Desktop\Genius Grid\Transcode-service\input\c9fcf43726e617a295b203d5acb7b81658b5f05f80eafc74cee21b053422fef1.mp4, correct? It seems strange to me that you are reading an entire MPEG into memory but it's not illegal. Also, does Windows allow the / character in filenames?

.\SampleVideo_1280x720_30mb.mp4 was only used to test whether or not command-line transcoding with hls was functional.  C:\Users\asifa\Desktop\Genius Grid\Transcode-service\input\c9fcf43726e617a295b203d5acb7b81658b5f05f80eafc74cee21b053422fef1.mp4 this is the MPEG data comes from fronted to transcode. After transcoding i will store the transcoded output in to S3 bucket and delete locally saved MPEG input and transcoded output. I'm creating a random name for incoming MPEG data from the frontend using the randomName() function.

Okay, so two things: (1) Is that file being saved valid? (I assume it is, because:) (2) Is this a valid parameter: Error: ffmpeg exited with code 2880417800: Unrecognized option 'hls_segment_filename C:\Users\asifa\Desktop\Genius Grid\Transcode-service\output\hls\c9fcf43726e617a295b203d5acb7b81658b5f05f80eafc74cee21b053422fef1/c9fcf43726e617a295b203d5acb7b81658b5f05f80eafc74cee21b053422fef1_256x144_%03d.ts'. ?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
